# Пояснительная запятая - нужна или нет

Tags: пунктуация

Я родился в Узбекистане (,) в городе Ташкент...

Answer (score 2):

Я родился в Узбекистане , в городе Ташкенте.- да, потому что от широкого названия идёт к узкому, конкретному. Это уточнение. И не в городе Ташкент, а в городе Ташкенте. Со словом "город" имя собственное согласуется в падеже.

Answer (score 0):

> И не в городе Ташкент, а в городе Ташкенте

А в школе учат совсем наоборот: если есть слово "город", то название его должно быть только в именительном падеже. А если в предложении только само название,тогда оно будет изменяться по падежам.

Comment: Не знаю, где Вас так учат. Я учитель и учу как положено:
      
  Склоняются: 
а) простые (не сложносоставные и не выраженные словосочетаниями) русские, славянские и освоенные названия городов, рек, сел, деревень, поселков, хуторов, усадеб, станиц, кроме оканчивающихся на гласные -о (о топонимах на -о см. здесь), -е, -и, -ы: в городе Москве, в городе Софии, из города Уфы, близ города Рыбинска, из города Кустаная, в городе Перми, на реке Светлой (но в городе Сумы, к поселку Дибуны, в городе Мытищи, в селе Горки).Подробнее здесь:
   http://www.gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.3

Comment: Присоединяюсь к Людмиле.  А Вы, Инна,  путаете употребление названий городов с употреблением приложений типа в романе "Война и мир",  но в "Войне и мире".

Comment: >А в школе учат совсем наоборот: если есть слово "город", то название его должно быть только в именительном падеже

Кошмар. Вы про эту школу в Минобр напишите.